# How to display 2 different column from mysql database in 1 column datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview

Here is my table. [table patient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdB0v.png)

I want firstname and lastname to be combined as "name" in datagridview, how can i do this?

here is my output [My output of datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftiy9.png)

And my code..

```
private void frmPatient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database = nuclinic; username = root; password = ; Convert Zero Datetime=True");

        string query = "select firstname, lastname from patient";

        using (MySqlDataAdapter adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con))
        {

            DataSet dset = new DataSet();

            adpt.Fill(dset);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I tried this code `"SELECT firstname + ', ' + lastname AS name"`;
but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use the MySQL CONCAT function to concatenate two columns and results into one column as given as name. You can use this to display in the grid view.

```
select   CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) as name, firstname, lastname from patient
```

Comment: Wow awesome! It worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Now my problem is solved !

Answer (score 2):

**Replace this**

```
string query = "select firstname, lastname from patient";
```

**with this**

```
string query = "select CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) as FullName from Patient";
```

*Concat Function Combine both name with space sperated*

**AS FullName(Column Name) return as that Column Name**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) as Name from Patient
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou very much ! This worked fine for me, awesome!